# How do I write equations for this Fibonacci sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, article-writing

The Fibonacci sequence can be defined using the recurrence relations:

$F_0 = 0, F_1=1, F_{n} =  F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}~~$ for $n \in \mathbb{N} \colon n \geq 2~~~$ (**1**)

$ F_0 = 0, F_1=1, F_{m+2} =  F_m + F_{m+1}~~$ for $m \in \mathbb{N} \colon m \geq 0~~~$    (**2**)

I believe that these definitions describe the same sequence.

I wish to specify functions in an *appropriate mathematical form* that specifies the computation of the $i^{th}$ Fibonacci number based on (**1**) and (**2**). Are my attempts below reasonable? I am interested in the correct mathematical notation, I already have working computer programs for both cases.

With respect to sequence (**1**) I think that the following conditional equation is OK.

$ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~fib \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$
\begin{equation}
fib(n)=\begin{cases}
   0, & \text{if $n=0$ }\\
   1, & \text{if $n=1$ }\\
            fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2), & \text{if $~n \geq 2$. Assume safe subtraction}
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Where safe, or truncated, subtraction always result in a natural number $~~\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$
\begin{eqnarray}
    0 - x = 0 \\
    x - 0 = x\\
    suc(x)  - suc(y)  = x - y
\end{eqnarray}
With respect to sequence (**2**) I am not too sure. My first attempt is:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ fib \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$
\begin{equation}
fib(m)=\begin{cases}
   0, & \text{if $m=0$ }\\
   1, & \text{if $m=1$ }
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~fib(m + 2) = fib(m) + fib(m +1)$

My problem seems to be that I cannot include the last line within the brace because the condition does not relate solely to $m$.

**Edit 1**: Maybe it would be better to write the function definition for (**2**) using multiple equations to specify a piecewise function.

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~fib \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

\begin{eqnarray}
fib(0) &=& 0\\fib(1) &=& 1\\fib(m + 2) &=& fib(m) + fib(m + 1)
\end{eqnarray}
The last equation handles cases where $m \geq 2$. The original  (**2**) specifies all case where $m \geq 0$. So I need the two special cases of $m=0$ and $m=1$.

Can these attempts in writing a function for (**2**) be improved?

**Edit 2**: Trying to write a function based on sequence (**2**) using a *single* conditional equation could give:

$$
fib(m + 2)=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
0, & (m+2) = 0\\
1. & (m+1) = 1\\
fib(m)+fib(m+1), & m \gt 0\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
In **Edit 2**, the Fibonacci numbers are calculated using $fib(m)+fib(m+1)$ from (**2**) but the condition used are different from (**2**). I am not sure that the **Edit 2** function is actually defined for $m=0$ and $m=1$, because $m$ must be negative for the first two cases. But I think that it is defined for $0,1,2,3,4, \dots$.

Maybe my sequence (**1**) is not specified correctly with $n\geq 2$, should it be  $n\geq 0$? In both cases the sequence is defined from $0 \dots n$ and $0 \dots m$ respectively, with two special cases, but should the condition be $m,n\geq 0$ for both (**1**) and (**2**) and the condition $n,m\geq 2$ sould be used in the definition of the functions?

Here is the Haskell code for (**2**) using Peano arithmetic for `plus`.

```
data Nat = Zero | Suc Nat deriving (Eq,Show)

fib Zero = Zero 
fib (Suc Zero) = Suc Zero
fib (Suc (Suc n)) = plus (fib n)  (fib (Suc n))
```

Comment: This is not clear.  Of course the two recursions are the same.  Just replace the "$n$" in the firs one with "$n+2$" and adjust the range.  To write out the second, just use a different letter to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbered conditions are equivalent *facts about* the sequence, but a *definition* of the sequence must tell us how to compute $F_n$, and in this respect the two facts (well, two *fact statements* since they're the same fact) give us the same definition. In Python terms, they both say `fib = lambda n: 0 if n==0 else 1 if n==1 else fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)` (minus some subtleties we needn't consider such as how to avoid an infinite regress if $n$ isn't a non-negative integer, the fact that this isn't the most efficient computation etc.)

However, there is some value to ($2$) if we rearrange its last equation as $F_n=F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}$, for computing the negative-$n$ cases viz. `fib = lambda n: 0 if n==0 else 1 if n==1 else fib(n-1)+fib(n-2) if n>=2 else fib(n+2)-fib(n+1)` (again, not worrying about issues such as `n` needing to be an integer for this to work).

Since you mention *pattern matching*, suppose we work in a programming language for which `n+2` can denote $2$ more than a non-negative integer. Then we can modify my first definition of `fib` on non-negative integers with a pattern-match that deals with cases other than `n==0` and `n==1`. (This is a more complicated variant of [pattern-matching to recursively compute factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching#Primitive_patterns), which only needs the single most recent term.) And again, the rearrangement of (2) would let us use a more complex pattern matching to compute $F_n$ for any integer $n$. I'll leave you to flesh out the details in your favourite language-or-pseudocode syntax.

Edit: in light of the OP's update, I think what's being requested is$$F_{n}=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
0 & n=0\\
1 & n=1\\
F_{n-1}+F_{n-2} & n\ge2\\
F_{n+2}-F_{n+1} & n<0
\end{array}\right..$$

Comment: @J,G Thanks for the feedback. I have edited the question to focus on the appropriate mathematical notation.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne Thanks. Does my edit help you?

Comment: Yes it helps. But with the restriction to natural numbers I am not sure that n can be less than zero.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne Just remove the last row, then.